# Is an integral identically zero

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Let $f$ be a continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that 
$$f(x,y+L)=f(x,y),\quad L\in \mathbb{R}, L>0$$
and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\neq 0$$

Suppose $$F(x,z)=\displaystyle\int_{z}^{z+L}  f(x,y) dy$$
and that $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}= 0=\frac{\partial F}{\partial z},$$
i.e. $F$ is constant. Is $F$ identically zero?

Comment: Consider $f(x,y) = 1 + g(x)\cos(2\pi y/L)$, for some arbitrary function $g$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Interesting, thank you!